# IE6 VM in VirtualBox on Mac freezing

Tags: macos, internet-explorer-6, virtualbox

I'm having trouble with getting IE6 to start up in VirtualBox in MacOSX. I had it working before a few weeks ago, but it has now started asking me to activate the licence (I was aware this might happen). So I figured the best course of action was to delete that VM, and download another from http://www.modern.ie/ (where I had got it the first time). I cannot for the life of me remember where I'd read instructions before on installing it, but did find this link: http://chriswharton.me/2013/02/installing-modern-ie-virtualization-on-virtualbox-for-mac/

Although when I extract the zip file from 'IE6_WinXP.ova.zip' using 'Archive Utility' I'm left with these two files: IE6 - WinXP-disk1.vmdk & IE6 - WinXP.ovf. Not a .ova file to be seen.

So instead I load up VirtualBox & click on New. I give it a name, type is Microsoft Windows, and version is Windows XP. Then I change the RAM to 1024MB & then choose the Virtual Hard Drive extracted from the zip: 'IE6 - WinXP-disk1.vmdk'. After the VM is created, I try and load it, but gets as far as a boot menu then freezes.

I also tried just double-clicking on the .ovf file & create a VM like that, but it doesn't even get to a boot menu.

Now I'm not hugely technical when it comes to this stuff. I'm just a humble web designer wanting, sorry, having, to test in IE6 :)

BTW don't even get me started on why I have to still support the wrinkly old IE6(!). I hate it with a passion, but certain international financial institutions still use it unfortunately, and the work I'm doing is specifically for them...

Any suggestions much appreciated!

FYI I'm using Mac OS X 10.8.4, and VirtualBox 4.2.16.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while, but still -

Give its base memory 512 MB, and 2 processors, make sure it boots on hard disk first. That did the trick for me.